# UseEffect hook keeps getting executed even when the dependency is not changed. (router.query)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('apply filter');    
   const newFilters = {
     status: {
       values: { label: router.query.status, value: router.query.status },
     },
     // Add other filter properties here...
   };    
   setFilters(newFilters);
}, [router.query]);
```

UseEffect hook keeps getting executed even when the dependency is not changed. I am using it to track change in router.query

I debugged to a extent, it is rerendering because the useEffect hook gets triggered in initial render no matter whether dependency changes or not and state is set and the component mounts again and its stuck in a loop. how do I solve this?

Comment: can you show Minimal reproductive example. Without your code, It's hard to tell what exactly is wrong?

Comment: You have to check your HOC components for state changes, it could trigger at state changes unnecessarily your child components and cause this side effect. But to be really sure that your router.query is not changing, create for it a `useMemo()`and save it to a variable. Then you can set the variable inside the `useEffect(() => {}, [ ... ]` -> dependency to go for sure not to trigger it unnecessarily without changes.

Comment: @ 
DecPKI debugged to a extent, it is rerendering because the useEffect hook gets triggered in initial render no matter whether dependency changes or not and state is set and the component mounts again and its stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency is an object, it may be changed even the value is the same. If it's not the same reference.

In your case, if the status is not an object. You can simply avoid using an object as the dependency.

Here is an example.

```js
// if you need other properties, write {status, key2, key3 ... }
const { status } = router.query

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('apply filter');    
   const newFilters = {
     status: {
       values: { label: status, value: status },
     },
     // Add other filter properties here...
   };    
   setFilters(newFilters);

// if you use more deps write [status, key2, key3 ... ]
}, [status]);
```

Comment: still stuck in the same loop with this

Comment: A good rule for the dependency array of useEffect is to try and only put primitive values in there. 

What is the value of `status`  Is it also an object?  Does calling `setFilters` change the value of `status`?